Open scrolled to bottom Chrome pages using batch
I wrote a script that opens a certain page in chrome profiles.
I want to add a command so that the page opens when scrolled all the way down.
Does anyone know what I should add?
set ProfileNames=("Profile 1" "Profile 2" "Profile 3")

for %%i in %ProfileNames% do (
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="%%~i" "https://edition.cnn.com")

I tried using the command window.scrollTo but it didn't work.
Maybe I'm not using it right...

The code you have submitted does not attempt any scrolling, and batch files cannot interact with your GUI application. This site does not provide code for you, it just helps to fix code which fails to perform a task it was written to perform.

For that particular site (cnn.com), the page has a HTML section called pageFooter.
<footer data-uri="cms.cnn.com/_components/footer/instances/us-v2@published" id="pageFooter" data-editable="settings" class="footer cnn-app-display-none" data-analytics-aggregate-events="true">...
</footer>

It's possible to use the URL https://edition.cnn.com/#pageFooter to go directly to this section when opening the page.
So change
start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="%%~i" "https://edition.cnn.com")

to this
start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="%%~i" "https://edition.cnn.com/#pageFooter")

